# How to scroll an element into view inside a window opened with window.open()

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

```js
var x = 582,y = 500,w = 200,h = 200;
var term = Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8);
var win = window.open(`https://www.example.com/search?q=${term}`, "", "width=" + w + ",height=" + h+",status=no");
win.moveTo(x, y);
win.document.scroll(0,findPos(win.document.getElementById("id_rc")));
```

Works as normal, but when the window is opened, the element is not scrolled into view.

Comment: Try opening URL with `#id_rc` added to it, browser should auto-scroll to it as it does with all links

Comment: @Justinas Thank you, this worked. Wish this was posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your desired ID into URL itself (`#id_rc`), so that browser would automatically scroll that element to view, just like with normal references in URL:

```js
var x = 582,y = 500,w = 200,h = 200;
var term = Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8);
var win = window.open(`https://www.example.com/search?q=${term}#id_rc`, "", "width=" + w + ",height=" + h+",status=no");
win.moveTo(x, y);
```